# Why does $a^{m_1}=a^{m_2}$ imply $a^{m_1-m_2}=e$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, proof-explanation, abelian-groups

I was reading [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/643618/639698). I understand almost all of it. However, there is still one thing that continues to puzzle me.

How should I prove for sure that, in this example, if $m_1\neq m_2$ and $a^{m_1}=a^{m_2}$, then $a^{m_1-m_2}=e$.

This proof expects me to know exactly why this holds true. Am I missing something?

I don't quite get why this is the case. What is the proof behind this assertion?

I guess I can see why $a^0=e$ but how can I be certain that this holds true for cases such as the one presented above?

Thank you!

Comment: Two lemmas: (1) If $gh=g$ then $h=e, $ and (2) $a^{m}a^{n}=a^{m+n}.$

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 3):

One way to look at $a^{-m_2}$ is $$a^{-m_2}=\underbrace{a^{-1}\times \dots \times a^{-1}}_{m_2\text{ times}},$$ so if we multiply $a^{m_1}=a^{m_2}$ on one side, say, the right, then we have

$$\begin{align}
a^{m_1}a^{-m_2}&=\underbrace{a\times \dots \times a}_{m_1\text{ times}}\times \underbrace{a^{-1}\times \dots\times a^{-1}}_{m_2\text{ times}} \\
&=a^{m_1-m_2} \\
&=\underbrace{a\times \dots \times a}_{m_2\text{ times}}\times\underbrace{a^{-1}\times \dots\times  a^{-1}}_{m_2\text{ times}} \\
&=a^{m_2}a^{-m_2}\\
&=e.
\end{align}$$

Answer (score 2):

If $$a^{m_1} = a^{m_2}$$ then by multiplying by $a^{-m_2}$ both sides we get $$a^{m_1}a^{-m_2} = a^{m_2}a^{-m_2}$$
The left hand side turns out to be $a^{m_1-m_2}$ while the right hand side is $e$.

Comment: For the "turns out to be" part, it might help to expand out the powers. By definition, $a^{m_1} = \underbrace{a a a \ldots a}_{m_1 \text{ times}}$, etc.

Comment: @6005 Looks like Shaun already done that. Good idea though.